# How much of the Merlin engine is made by 3D printing?

Tags: merlin-1d

How much of the Merlin engine is made by 3D printing?

Is the nozzle, the valve, the combustion chamber? How about turbo pumps?

Comment: Not so secret:  In 2014, the SuperDraco thruster turned out to be the first fully printed rocket engine to ever see flight, as it went on to power the Dragon spacecraft’s launch escape system

Comment: Was the wiring printed on the SuperDraco?

Comment: I wish I know. Same q for hoses and screws

Comment: Which engine are you asking about? Merlin (in the title), or Raptor (in the body of the question)?